# Mobilepush api routing with two Mobile Apps connected to one BusinessUnit

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

I need to connect two apps to the same businessunit. I noticed this is possible in the mobilepush 'Administration' tab, and I can select to which app I want to send a push message in journeybuilder.

My question is, how do I select which app to use when I want to send push messages via the mobilepush API?
We are primarily going to use this API:  
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageContactSendPush.html

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messageID is only for one app.

You select the app when you create the message

[image]